# Formula field conditions

Tags: formula-field

We have lot of conditions to be set for a formula field as below. Is it possible to have these many conditions to be included in a formula field?

```
if( Source__c =="Manual" || Source__c == "Hardcopy" )
{
    if(Outcome__c=="PASS" && Expiry_Date__c>=Today() )
    {
        Status__c = "Verified"
    }
    else
    {
        if(Outcome__c=="PASS" && Expiry_Date__c<Today())
        {
            Status__c = "Expired"
        }
        else
        {
            if( Outcome__c=="FAIL" || TEXT(Outcome__c)=="Invalid" )
            {
                Status__c = "Invalid"
            }
            else
            {
                Status__c = "Not Verified"
            }
                
        }
    }
}
else if( Source__c=="Online" )
{
    if(Outcome__c=="PASS" )
    {
        Status__c = "Verified"
    }
    else if( Outcome__c=="FAIL" || TEXT(Outcome__c)=="Invalid" )
    {
        Status__c = "Invalid"
    }
    else
    {
        Status__c = "Not Verified"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes/no questions aren't a great fit for this site. The answer here is "yes" (this doesn't seem like a particularly large set of conditions to check for me). This would be a better question if you [edit] your question to  show us what you've tried so far (to try to turn this into a formula field) and point out a specific thing that you're stuck on.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Have you tried it, and are you having a specific issue?

Comment: One hint I will give you right away is that you do have an opportunity to simplify things a little. Where do you see something that doesn't depend on the value of `Source__c`? If it doesn't depend on `Source__c`, then it can be brought out of the if/else blocks that do depend on that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula should be like below.

```
OR(
   IF( 
      OR(ISPICKVAL(Source__c,"Manual"),ISPICKVAL(Source__c,"Hardcopy")),
       If(AND(ISPICKVAL(Outcome__c,"PASS"),Expiry_Date__c>=Today()),"Verified",
          If(AND(ISPICKVAL(Outcome__c,"PASS"),Expiry_Date__c>=Today()), "Expired",
             If(OR(ISPICKVAL(Outcome__c,"FAIL"),ISPICKVAL(Outcome__c,"Invalid"))"Invalid","Not Verified"
               )
            )
         ),
      ''
    ),
  IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Source__c,"Online"),
    If(ISPICKVAL(Outcome__c,"PASS"),"Verified",
       IF(OR(ISPICKVAL(Outcome__c,"FAIL"),ISPICKVAL(Outcome__c,"Invalid"))"Invalid","Not Verified")
      ),
    ''
    )
  )
```

|| (OR)

> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns TRUE if any
> expression is true. Returns FALSE if all expressions are false.
>
> Use this function as an alternative to the operator || (OR)
>
> Use `OR(logical1, logical2...)` and replace any number of logical
> references with the expressions you want evaluated.

AND

> Returns a TRUE response if all values are true; returns a FALSE
> response if one or more values are false.
>
> Use the && (AND) function as an alternative to the operator.
>
> Use `AND(logical1,logical2,...)` and replace logical1,logical2,... with
> the values that you want evaluated.

IF

> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns a given value if
> true and another value if false.
>
> Use `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)` and replace
> logical_test with the expression you want evaluated; replace
> value_if_true with the value you want returned if the expression is
> true; replace value_if_false with the value you want returned if the
> expression is false.

Refer the [Formula Operators and Functions by Context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5)